Inductive Automation Jython 2.7 Script - Issues with TCP Exhaustion When doing an MQTT Publish
So i am using some gateway timer scripts multiple executing every 60s.
The issue i am running into is after a few days the windows server ignition is on locks up network wise due to TCP Port exhaustion i believe. When troubleshooting I can consistently watch the TCP connections increase. I have added debugging to the script and its showing that it is disconnecting from the connection. But the TCP connections just keep increasing.
Looking for some advice on how to manage this.
import json
import time
import ssl
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from collections import OrderedDict

# Define the MQTT broker details
broker_address = "a24qeh3kq5ixg0-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
port = 8883
certs_path = r"C:\Users\Public\Documents\client_mqtt_certificates\Divconbroker1"

keepalive = 45

# Define the base tag path
base_tag_path = "[default]MQTT Tags/Databank_Phase1/ATL75_All-Rooms"

# Define the path for the connection status tag
connection_status_tag_path = "[default]NO_BROKER_CONNECTION"

# Function to check if certificate files exist
def check_cert_files(certs_path, os_module):
    ca_cert_file = os_module.path.join(certs_path, "AWSRootCA1.pem")
    cert_file = os_module.path.join(certs_path, "certificate.pem.crt")
    key_file = os_module.path.join(certs_path, "private.pem.key")

    for file_path in [ca_cert_file, cert_file, key_file]:
        if not os_module.path.isfile(file_path):
            raise Exception("File not found: {}".format(file_path))
    
    return ca_cert_file, cert_file, key_file

# Check certificate files
import os  # Importing os outside functions and passing it explicitly
ca_cert_file, cert_file, key_file = check_cert_files(certs_path, os)

# Function to initialize MQTT client
def initialize_mqtt_client(broker_address, port, ca_cert_file, cert_file, key_file, mqtt_module, ssl_module, keepalive):
    client = mqtt_module.Client()
    client.tls_set(ca_certs=ca_cert_file,
                   certfile=cert_file,
                   keyfile=key_file,
                   tls_version=ssl_module.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    
    client.connected_flag = False  # Create flag in client object

    def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
        pass

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            client.connected_flag = True  # Set flag when connected

    def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
        pass

    client.on_publish = on_publish
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_log = on_log

    try:
        client.connect(broker_address, port, keepalive)
        client.loop_start()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    return client

# Function to check MQTT connection
def check_mqtt_connection(client, timeout=10, time_module=None):
    if time_module is None:
        import time as time_module  # Ensure time is imported within the function scope
    for _ in range(timeout):
        if client.connected_flag:
            return True
        time_module.sleep(1)
    return False

# Function to process a single device
def process_device(device, client, time_module, system, OrderedDict, json_module):
    try:
        device_name = device['name']
        if device['hasChildren']:
            tags = system.tag.browse(device['fullPath'])
            tag_paths = [str(tag['fullPath']) for tag in tags.getResults()]

            if tag_paths:
                tag_values = system.tag.readBlocking(tag_paths)
                tag_data = OrderedDict()
                unit_paths = [tag_path + ".EngUnit" for tag_path in tag_paths]
                units = system.tag.readBlocking(unit_paths)

                for tag, tag_value, unit in zip(tags.getResults(), tag_values, units):
                    tag_quality = tag_value.quality
                    value = "Bad Quality" if not tag_quality.isGood() else tag_value.value
                    tag_timestamp = tag_value.timestamp if tag_quality.isGood() else None

                    if value != "Bad Quality":
                        tag_name = tag['name']
                        tag_data[tag_name] = OrderedDict([
                            ("timestamp", int(tag_timestamp.getTime() / 1000)),
                            ("value", value),
                            ("unit", unit.value)
                        ])

                if tag_data:
                    device_path_str = str(device['fullPath'])
                    device_path_parts = device_path_str.split("/")
                    device_type = device_path_parts[-2]
                    location_name = device_path_parts[-3]

                    base_payload = OrderedDict([
                        ("deviceType", device_type),
                        ("deviceName", device_name),
                        ("location", location_name),
                        ("timestamp", int(time_module.time())),
                    ])

                    tag_items = list(tag_data.items())
                    sequence_number = 0
                    max_chunk_size = 128 * 1024

                    while tag_items:
                        current_chunk = OrderedDict()
                        current_size = 0
                        while tag_items and current_size < max_chunk_size:
                            tag_item = tag_items.pop(0)
                            tag_item_json = json_module.dumps({tag_item[0]: tag_item[1]})
                            if current_size + len(tag_item_json) > max_chunk_size:
                                tag_items.insert(0, tag_item)
                                break
                            current_chunk[tag_item[0]] = tag_item[1]
                            current_size += len(tag_item_json)

                        payload = base_payload.copy()
                        payload["tags"] = current_chunk
                        topic_suffix = "" if sequence_number == 0 else "/" + str(sequence_number)
                        full_topic = "Databank/ATL75/Phase1/All-Rooms/" + device_type + "/" + device_name + topic_suffix

                        payload_json = json_module.dumps(payload)

                        result = client.publish(full_topic, payload_json, qos=1)
                        result.wait_for_publish()

                        sequence_number += 1
    except Exception:
        pass

try:
    # Initialize the client
    client = initialize_mqtt_client(broker_address, port, ca_cert_file, cert_file, key_file, mqtt, ssl, keepalive)
    
    connection_successful = check_mqtt_connection(client, time_module=time)

    if not connection_successful:
        system.tag.writeBlocking([connection_status_tag_path], [True])
        raise Exception("Failed to connect to the broker.")
    else:
        system.tag.writeBlocking([connection_status_tag_path], [False])

    tag_structure = system.tag.browse(base_tag_path)

    for location in tag_structure.getResults():
        if location['hasChildren']:
            devices = system.tag.browse(location['fullPath'])
            for device in devices.getResults():
                process_device(device, client, time_module=time, system=system, OrderedDict=OrderedDict, json_module=json)

except Exception:
    system.tag.writeBlocking([connection_status_tag_path], [True])
finally:
    if client is not None:
        client.loop_stop()
        client.disconnect()



Based on your callback signitures it looks like you are using an old (pre v2) version of paho-mqtt please confirm what version is in use. "showing that it is disconnecting" please include these logs in your question (and ideally full logs). Note that disconnect() assumes the network loop is running (and should terminate the loop process when the disconnect completes); I suspect this may be your issue.
